# Changing sub plot titles in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, economics

When I run this code

```py
irf_colombia = model_fitted.irf(16)
irf_colombia.plot(orth=True,figsize=(50,20),subplot_params={"fontsize":16}).set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=150, h_pad=6, wspace=20, hspace=6)
plt.show()
```

I get this

[image: 1]

I would like to change the sub plots titles. What should I do?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the subplots using something like `axs = plt.gcf().get_axes()` and then set individual titles, e.g., `axs[0,0].set_title("New Title")`